# Retrieve data from Firestore to DropdownButtonFormField as initial value so it can be updated

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, dropdown

I have a working code for TextFormField

```
          TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Full name'),
                  initialValue: output!['full_name'],
                  onFieldSubmitted: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      newUserName = val;
                      print(val);
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('users')
                          .doc(widget.userId)
                          .update({'full_name': newUserName});
                    });
                  },
                ),
```

As you can see, I signed the stored username as the initialValue. Then, after the user changes it, it is update in Firestore after field is submitted.

This is where I want to do it:

```
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Select gender'),

validator: (val) => (val == null || val.isEmpty) ? 'Fill the field' : null,
isExpanded: true,
value: _selectedValue,
items: items.map(buildMenuItem).toList(),
onChanged:setState: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedValue = val;
                  });
                }),
 )
```

`items` is a simple `List<String>` with the options.

Comment: cant really understand what you want ?

Comment: @WaliKhan  I'll try my best. First, the user creates a profile (where will complete with, for example, full name (TextFormField) and gender(DropDownButtonFormField). These datas are stored in Firestore. Let's suppose someone wants to change the gender data. Then, the person will go to profile page, where the current stored value in the dropdown will be the gender he/she selected in the beginning. The, he/she will have the same options as before to change it. After selecting the new value, it is updated in Firestore

Answer (score 2):

in `initState()`  use dropDownValue = dataFromFireBase;
and in `DropdownButtonFormField` set value to dropDownValue

this is an example:

```
  String dropDownValue ='';
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dropDownValue  = dataFromFireBase;
   }
```

Your dropDown :

```
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
            value: dropDownValue,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            iconSize: 24,
            elevation: 16,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            onChanged: (String? newValue) {
              setState(() {
                dropDownValue  = newValue!;
              });
            },
            items: ['your List'],
          ),
```

For more information you can also refer to the [stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58719690/flutter-rendering-list-from-firebase-based-on-condition-in-dropdown-menu) where a similar issue has been discussed, I hope this answer is helpful.